# Better approach for a Wordpress Inventory

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, front-end

I am building a Inventory project just to learn wordpress more.

Now scenario is like this . when the admin adds a new *product* from **Front-end** and **not** from wp-admin.

So when I add a product from UI. First option will be Product *company name*. Now there will be a `dropdown` for all product company name which were added before. So I can choose the appropriate *company name* . Now if a particular company name is not there then I will have a option to add a New Company Name from a `textbox` and then it will show in the `dropdown` of Companies name.

What my approach is that I will make company names as `Categories`. I will display the `categories` with a specific `slug` *(=companyname)*  as Company name in a dropdown. on adding a new company name I will add as a new `category`.

**Every product will be a `custom post type`**.

Now Next field will be Type of product  so this field will be a `sub category` or another `category` with a specific `slug` so that it can be used for any company name (which is a `category` itself)

Am I on a right track? Am making any mistake ? Can I do it in much better way. 
Your expert advice please

Answer (score 1):

In general, `categories` are tied to `posts` only (not custom types). This is built-in taxonomy. Though there is [another experience](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-categories-to-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/).

My approach is to create custom post types and custom taxonomies. That's up to you how to organize the catalog. CPT for company and taxonomy for product family, or otherwise:

```
/makita/drills/product_1
/makita/drills/product_2
/bosch/drills/product_1
/bosch/drills/product_1
```

or

```
/drills/makita/product_1
/drills/makita/product_2
/drills/bosch/product_1
/drills/bosch/product_2
```

Both CPTs and taxonomies can be hierarchical, so you'll get "*subcategories*" in any way:

```
/drills/cordless/makita/product_1
```

or

```
makita/drills/cordless/product_1
```

or

```
/drills/makita/cordless/product_1
```

**Note**, you have to plan your theme template hierarchy first to avoid difficulties in future.

Comment: So you mean to say my approach is okay. product as  CPT and fields like company name as Taxonomy